# Elastic search 5.0 duplicate removal/optimisation

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, duplicates, kibana

From ES 5.0 Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default., How I could remove duplicates/ achieve the same result with existing settings i.e. when field data is disabled on query below?

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "query": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
     ,
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }


      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "query": {

          "multi_match": {
            "query": "laura",
            "operator": "OR",
            "fields": [

              "name"

            ]
          }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Yes, error 400. https://jsfiddle.net/68zjzp0p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to [enable fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_enabling_fielddata_on_literal_text_literal_fields) on text fields for **ES 5.x**. Use it with [caution](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default) as it consumes lot of heap space.

Update your mapping with

```
PUT your_index/_mapping/your_type
{
  "properties": {
    "name": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

and then run the query.